# Word for saying something that people want to hear

Tags: politics

Justin Trudeau, the Canadian Prime Minister-designate, recently (rather impotently) rebuked his supporters in front of the media for booing a question posed by a reporter, saying,

> Hey, guys, guys, hey!  We have respect for journalists in this country.  They ask tough questions and they're supposed to, ok?

Video link: http://www.cbc.ca/player/News/Politics/ID/2677142273/

**Assuming we believe he is feigning outrage**, what is a good word to describe this?  *Grandstanding* or *pandering* are suitable, but I wonder if there's something more appropriate.

Comment: *Playing to the audience/crowd* ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"demagogic" proposed by @Elian perfectly fits the answer title, i.e. "Word for saying something that people want to hear".

But, it doesn' cover the other issue mentionned in the question, the "insincere" or "hypocrite" aspect of such **specious** speech.

> Specious definition: falsely appearing to be fair, just, or right;
>   appearing to be true but actually false.

*Finally, a **specious demagogue** may fit.*

Comment: Thank you.  *specious* is exactly the adjective I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

How about **demagogic**?

> **demagogue**
>
> : a person who gains the support of the public by making impassioned
>   speeches that appeal to their emotions and prejudices.

[Dictionary of Unfamiliar Words](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/demagogue)

Comment: I think rabble-rousing is about making crowds go angry and violent.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say he's trying to **score points** with the crowd.

> score points: to do something **that will make people like you**

(http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/score+points)